# Gsettings and dconf-editor touchpad settings not being used

Tags: touchpad, dconf

So, I am used to disabling my touchpad send-events on external mouse via gsettings, and even when trying with dconf-editor, it no longer works.

Thus I am stuck disabling the touchpad with

```
synclient TouchPadOff=1
```

And honestly, it's a huge bother.

Anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your touchpad has switched to using the synaptics driver instead of the libinput driver.

You could try removing the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package if it is installed. The libinput driver will already be installed, so it should be a case of removing this package and then rebooting for the libinput driver to be picked up.

Comment: So, I have removed the package you suggested, now, is it a matter of rebooting and having the libinput driver just work, or is there a libinput package that I should be installing?

Comment: Okay, so to answer my question, yes, I rebooted and it now works.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, it was late last night when I wrote this answer. I've updated my answer to include that information. If you're happy with it, you could mark it as the accepted answer.